# Airflow - trying to loop an operator. The execution is not waiting for actual operation to complete

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

In Airflow - I'm trying to loop an operator. (BigQueryOperator). The DAG completes even before the query finishes.

What my DAG it essentially does is :

1. Read a set of insert queries one by one.
2. trigger each query using BigQueryOperator.

When I'm trying to write 2 records (with 2 insert statements) - after the job i can only see 1 record.

```
dag
bteqQueries = ReadFile() --Read GCP bucket file and get the list of SQL queries (as text) separated by new line

for currQuery in bteqQueries.split('\n'):
    #logging.info("currQuery : {}".format(currQuery))
     parameter = {
    'cur_query': currQuery
}
    logging.info("START $$ : {}".format(parameter.get('cur_query')))
    gcs2BQ = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs2bq_insert',
    bql=parameter.get('cur_query'),
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
    use_legacy_sql='False',
    dag=dag,
    task_concurrency=1)
    logging.info("END $$ : {}".format(parameter.get('cur_query')))


gcs2BQ
```

Expect all the queries in the Input file (in GCS bucket) to be executed. I had couple of insert queries and expect 2 records in the final bigquery table. But I only see 1 record.

********Below is the log ******

```
 2018-12-19 03:57:16,194] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,190] {gcs2BQ_bteq.py:59} INFO - START $$ : insert into `gproject.bucket.employee_test_stg.employee_test_stg` (emp_id,emp_name,edh_end_dttm) values (2,"srikanth","2099-01-01") ; 
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,205] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,201] {models.py:2190} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(BigQueryOperator): gcs2bq_insert>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,210] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,209] {gcs2BQ_bteq.py:68} INFO - END $$ : insert into `project.bucket.employee_test_stgemployee_test_stg` (emp_id,emp_name,edh_end_dttm) values (2,"srikanth","2099-01-01") ; 
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,213] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,213] {gcs2BQ_bteq.py:59} INFO - START $$ : insert into `project.bucket.employee_test_stg` (emp_id,emp_name,edh_end_dttm) values (3,"srikanth","2099-01-01") ;
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,223] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: 
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,218] {models.py:2190} WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(BigQueryOperator): gcs2bq_insert>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,230] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,230] {gcs2BQ_bteq.py:68} INFO - END $$ : insert into `dataset1.adp_etl_stg.employee_test_stg` (emp_id,emp_name,edh_end_dttm) values (3,"srikanth","2099-01-01") ;
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,658] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,655] {bigquery_operator.py:90} INFO - Executing: insert into `dataset1.adp_etl_stg.employee_test_stg` (emp_id,emp_name,edh_end_dttm) values (2,"srikanth","2099-01-01") ; 
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,703] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,702] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:74} INFO - Getting connection using `gcloud auth` user, since no key file is defined for hook.
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,848] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,847] {discovery.py:267} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest
[2018-12-19 03:57:16,849] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:16,849] {client.py:595} INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
[2018-12-19 03:57:17,012] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:17,011] {discovery.py:852} INFO - URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcp-***Project***/jobs?alt=json
[2018-12-19 03:57:17,214] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:17,214] {discovery.py:852} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcp-***Project***/jobs/job_jqrRn4lK8IHqTArYAVj6cXRfLgDd?alt=json
[2018-12-19 03:57:17,304] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:17,303] {bigquery_hook.py:856} INFO - Waiting for job to complete : gcp-***Project***, job_jqrRn4lK8IHqTArYAVj6cXRfLgDd
[2018-12-19 03:57:22,311] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-12-19 03:57:22,310] {discovery.py:852} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/gcp-***Project***/jobs/job_jqrRn4lK8IHqTArYAVj6cXRfLgDd?alt=json
```

Comment: Even if it is possible to write for loops directly within the DAG, it will not get executed like in a normal Python script. You need to put your loop into a function and call the function as an Airflow task with a `PythonOperator`.

Comment: When I tried this - the actual BigQueryOperator (gcs2BQ ) is not visible outside the function. Hence its not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```py
gcs2BQ = []
for index, currQuery in enumerate(bteqQueries.split('\n')):
    logging.info("currQuery : {}".format(currQuery))
    parameter = {
        'cur_query': currQuery
    }
    logging.info("START $$ : {}".format(parameter.get('cur_query')))
    gcs2BQ.append(BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcs2bq_insert_{}'.format(index),
        bql=parameter.get('cur_query'),
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
        use_legacy_sql='False',
        dag=dag,
        task_concurrency=1))
    logging.info("END $$ : {}".format(parameter.get('cur_query')))

    if index == 0:
        gcs2BQ[0]
    else:
        gcs2BQ[index - 1] >> gcs2BQ[index]
```

Basically, the `task_id` should be unique and you can specify an explicit dependency on queries using the code above.

Comment: thanks very much. This works. Is it possible to put this inside a python function and trigger? When I tried it - since the gcs2BQ operator is not in scope outside the function, it isn't getting triggered.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Can you accept that answer & upvote it ? :) . Regarding your other question: why do you want to put it inside a function? It is possible to put inside a function, for triggering just call out that function.

Comment: the looping part worked. But in the DAG, I tried to execute with 3 DMLs. it looped correctly and succeeded. Same DAG, when I tried to execute with 2 DMLs - it ran correctly for the 2 DMLs and shows a failure for 3rd task. can you please tell me why does it do that and how can we avoid it ?

Log :

[2019-01-03 02:39:02,157] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'Syntax error: Unexpected end of statement at [1:1]', u'location': u'query'}.